# Буква Ё в слове "блеклый"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Попался на одном сообщество вопрос: "Как правильно: блеклый или блёклый?" А действительно, как правильно?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Справка сайта Словари.ру отвечает:

Правильно и то и другое. Варианты слов – без дополнительных пометок – обычно приводятся в словарях в тех случаях, когда эти варианты равноправны в употреблении. У слов *блёклый* и *блеклый*, когда они даются вместе, помет никаких нет (Словарь Ожегова – Шведовой, Большой толковый словарь русского языка (СПб), Русский орфографический словарь), но все-таки эти слова – по ощущениям носителей языка – не равноправны. Более активно употребляется слово *блёклый*, только оно включено в Словарь русского языка под ред. Д. Н. Ушакова, в 4-томный академический словарь и в Словарь ударений. Орфоэпический словарь оценивает слово *блеклый* как менее желательный вариант в пределах нормы.

http://slovari.ru/default.aspx?p=1089

Справочник "Русская речь в эфире"2004 г. указывает вариант *блёклый* как единственный.

Answer (score 1):

блёклый будет правильно

Answer (score 1):

В словаре у Резниченко (2009 год): блеклый и блёклый (вариант с Ё на втором месте). В Грамоте.ру - наоборот.

Answer (score 0):

Слово "блЕклый" может быть использовано только с какой-то определённой целью, например, в стихотворении.